# If I submit a FOIA request to the CBP for entry and exit records, does it show travel between US states and US territories?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, domestic-travel, history

I wonder the following: If I submit a FOIA (Freedom of Information Act) request to the US CBP for entry and exit records, does it show travel between US states and US territories?

Comment: I would presume it does if and only if you need to pass through Immigration, which is only the case for some US territories.

Comment: @lambshaanxy it's also possible that it doesn't show them at all, even if there was a passport inspection, since such travel does not in fact constitute entry into the United States.  For example, there's no reason for someone to get a new I-94 when traveling between Puerto Rico and Florida.  (Though there is a separate Guam-CNMI visa waiver program, so it may be different for people traveling between thise places and other parts of the US, at least for some travelers.)